# How to manage UI in java code?

Tags: android, android-activity

Once I set the contentView to a layout, how can I manage the UI via java? Also, if I start a new activity, do I reset the contentView?

Comment: Improve the question and maybe your questions will be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ContentView will only be in one activity.

Assuming you are in something that extends `Activity` all you have to do, after setting content view, is access your views. Say you have a button in your layout:

```
Button homeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
homeButton.setText(); homeButton.setOnClickListener() etc
```

If you're in a dialog, or need to access certain views in specific circumstances, or you're in an intent and need to access stuff in your main activity's layout:

```
Button secondButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.secondButton);
//other methods on the button
```

EDITS--

Well images, you just add an ImageView into the layout:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

You don't need to do anything with code specifically, it should just show up.

Buttons and other views can also be added via XML. You can add things programmatically as well, though it's not as common.

If I remember correctly, the constructor to create a button in Java that's not in your XML file, it would be `Button aNewButton = new Button(getApplicationContext()); 
aNewButton.setText("whatever");`

Comment: what if I want to draw stuff to my layout? buttons not already on there, or images.

Comment: so I should create all my UI elements in XML before runtime and manipulate them during runtime?

Comment: Yep! It's actually very helpful. You can lay out the whole screen visually, before having to do one ounce of coding. Beyond that, imagine this situation: You download data from a internet server, let's just say first/last names. You know there will always be 5-10 name sets. So rather than having to know exactly how many name sets there are, you can just design it once. Then, for each set you get, you just add another copy of the one layout to the screen.

Comment: I actually created a renderUIThread to draw objects to screen before I found out about the XML layout. Do I no longer need this dedicated thread?

Comment: You do not. The default thread is the UI thread. Eventually you'll end up needing new threads, but not til you're working with network connections that affect the UI.